# React: Content is not adjusting right on form in webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, web, reactstrap

I am using ReactStrap to build my web application. This is my code:

```
class Address extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (

      <Media body>
        <Container>
          <Form>
            <FormGroup className="d-block">
              <Label for="address1">Address line 1</Label>
              <Input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" />
            </FormGroup>

            <Row form>
              <Col sm={5}>
                <FormGroup className="d-block">
                  <Label for="zip">ZIP</Label>
                  <Input type="text" name="text" id="zip" />
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>

              <Col sm={2}>
                <FormGroup className="d-block">
                  <Label for="state">State: </Label>
                  <Input type="select" name="select" id="state">
                    <option>IL</option>
                    <option>AZ</option>
                  </Input>
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>

              <Col sm={3} className="d-block">
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="Country">Country: </Label>
                  <Input type="select" name="select" id="Country">
                    <option>United States</option>
                    <option>Canada</option>
                  </Input>
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>
            </Row>

            <Button>Submit</Button>
          </Form>
        </Container>
      </Media>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is how it shows up in the web page:
[image]

I just want to know why it's not lining up on the left correctly and how to fix it. Thanks.

Edit: as Just code has informed me, it is because in the style.css, I have this:

```
form div {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

Comment: should render as it is, you must have other css which is causing this issue

Comment: Without the css we can see what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Daniel Doblado check the edit

Comment: Try setting the property fluid of `Container` to `true` https://reactstrap.github.io/components/layout/ you can see de difference with fluid in this example.